# Redefine fetch options type to accept object as body value too

Tags: typescript

The standard `fetch()` `BodyInit_` type does not allow objects to be assigned to `body`.

My custom wrapper around fetch should have the same signature as `fetch` but allow the second arguments (options) to have a body value that can be an object.

How would I override the type?

I have tried

```
type BodyInitType = RequestInit["body"]
type WrappedRequestInit = Exclude<RequestInit, "body"> & {
  body: object
}

type WrappedFetch = (url:string, options: WrappedRequestInit) => Promise<Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Omit` instead of `Exclude`

```js
type WrappedRequestInit = Omit<RequestInit, "body"> & {
    body:object
}

declare function fetch(input: RequestInfo, init: WrappedRequestInit): Promise<Response>
declare function fetch(input: RequestInfo, init: RequestInit): Promise<Response>
declare function fetch(input: RequestInfo, init?: WrappedRequestInit | RequestInit): Promise<Response>

const foo = fetch('http://example.com', {
    body: {} // ok
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to describe a functions signature and then get TS help when "implementing" such function?
Say `function:MyFunction(...)` and ts would infer/know the arguments?

Comment: Do you want to do it for fetch?

Comment: for a fetch middleware: https://github.com/benjamine/fetch-wrap

Comment: Could you please exactly point to some line of code?

Comment: because if you want to type `fetch`, this is the only way